# como crear un arreglo, donde se vayan guardando datos hasta que se finalice el programa, usando diferentes clases en java?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un proyecto de mi clase de programacion 1 en la cual consiste en hacer un juego donde habra un menu principal pque tendra estos botones:

1.crear jugador
2.iniciar sesion
3.salir.

entonces cree jframes para las opciones iniciar sesion, pero enfoquemonos en el jframe "crear jugador" yo hice una clase llamada jugador, donde almacene todos los metodos y variables que usare, aqui esta todo el codigo en la clase "jugador":

```
public class jugador {
    String nombUsuario;//variable que guardara el nombre de usuario
    private String contra;//esta variable guardara la contrasena
    String[] usuarios = new String[ 15 ];//crea un arreglo donde se guardaran todos los nombres de usuario
    String[] contras = new String[ 15 ];//crea un arreglo donde se guardaran todas las contrasenas.


//*****este metodo hace que se agregue un jugador***********
    public boolean agregarJugador(String nombUsuario, String contra){
        int y = 0;
        int x;
        for(x = 0; x <= 14; x++){
            if(usuarios[x] == null){
                y = x;
                break;
      }  
        }
        usuarios[y] = nombUsuario;
        contras[y] = contra; 
        return true;
    }
    public boolean comprobarJugador(String nombUsuarios, String contr){
        for(int n = 0;n <= 14; n++){
            if(nombUsuarios == usuarios[n] && contr == contras[n]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

y ahora en la clase llamada crearPlayer, que ahi tengo los textfield para agregar el usuario y contraseña a crearse y un boton llamado "Crear Player" entonces al darle crear player me lo guarda los valores escrito en usuario y contraseña, pero cuando(sin cerrar el programa) vuelvo a crearPlayer y agrego otro nombre de usuario y otra contrasena, no me lo guarda en el mismo arreglo que cree en la clase jugador, y bueno aca les dejo el codigo que esta en la clase crearPlayer:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author damasofc
     */
    public class crearPlayer extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        jugador jug = new jugador();
    /**
     * Creates new form crearPlayer
     */
    public crearPlayer() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jtf_usuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        bt_crearJugador = new javax.swing.JButton();
        bt_atras = new javax.swing.JButton();
        psw_contra = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Nuevo Jugador");

        jLabel2.setText("Usuario");

        jLabel3.setText("Contraseña");

        bt_crearJugador.setText("Crear Jugador");
        bt_crearJugador.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bt_crearJugadorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        bt_atras.setText("Atras");
        bt_atras.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bt_atrasActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 67, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGap(98, 98, 98))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jtf_usuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 119, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(psw_contra))
                                .addGap(81, 81, 81))))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(bt_atras)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(125, 125, 125)
                .addComponent(bt_crearJugador)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jtf_usuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(psw_contra, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(bt_crearJugador)
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addComponent(bt_atras)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void bt_crearJugadorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        //creo un objeto de la clase jugador
        // ******** ACA COMPRUEBA QUE SE HAYA AGREGADO EL JUGADOR CON EXITO Y SI ES ASI, MANDA UN MENSAJE DICIENDO: JUGADOR CREADO*****
        if(jug.comprobarJugador(jtf_usuario.getText(), psw_contra.getText()) == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Jugador ya existente","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else{
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Jugador ya existente","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if( jug.agregarJugador(jtf_usuario.getText(), psw_contra.getText()) == true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Jugador creado","Excelente",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                Menu_inicio pal = new Menu_inicio();//aca creo un objeto de la clase Menu_inicio
                this.setVisible(false);//aca se cierra esta ventana actual de crearPlayer
                pal.setVisible(true);//etso hace que se abra la ventana de Menu_inicio
        }
       }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jug.usuarios));

    }                                               

    private void bt_atrasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Menu_inicio pal = new Menu_inicio();//aca creo un objeto de la clase Menu_inicio
        pal.setVisible(true);//etso hace que se abra la ventana de Menu_inicio
        this.dispose();//aca se cierra esta ventana actual de crearPlayer
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crearPlayer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crearPlayer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crearPlayer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(crearPlayer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new crearPlayer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bt_atras;
    private javax.swing.JButton bt_crearJugador;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtf_usuario;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField psw_contra;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada te recomendería mirar más sobre la programación en Java. Las clases por norma deberían crearse con la primera letra en mayúscula tal que así: `Jugador`.
Tu clase debería tener un constructor, con el que poder crear un `Jugador`:

```
public Jugador (String nombre, String contraseña) 
{
    this.nombUsuario = nombre;
    this.contra = contraseña;
}
```

Tu problema está en que no puedes crear el array en la clase jugador, ya que cada vez que la inicializas con `new Jugador(...)` inicializas de nuevo cada uno de los array.
El array deberás tenerlo en una clase, o una pantalla "principal" o donde se vayan a mostrar los datos.
Por otra parte yo haría uso de `ArrayList` ya que es más cómodo que los `array`.

Inicializando el `ArrayList` de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
```

Y añadiendolos a esta lista así:

```
jugadores.add(new Jugador("Pepito", "1234"));
```

Por lo que tu método sería más sencillo:

```
public boolean agregarJugador(String nombUsuario, String contra){
    jugadores.add(nombUsuario, contra);
    return true;
}
```

> ¡Ojo! Tu `ArrayList`, como ya dije antes, deberías de tenerlo en el
>   formulario principal (por ejemplo) ya que no se va a instanciar varias
>   veces (o no debería). Para ello deberás hacer uso de `GETTER` o poner
>   tu `ArrayList` como público.

Añado enlace a un **[tutorial](https://jarroba.com/arraylist-en-java-ejemplos/)** bastante básico sobre `ArrayList` y que te podría ayudar.

Comment: enserio que muchas gracias, es mi primera vez haciendo preguntas aca, y me has respondido de una forma correcta y entendible, te lo agradezco, y si yo se que debo leer mas, porque apenas vengo empezando.